# Getting data from angular components

Tags: angularjs, components

Angular 1.5

I created component that by fact just form with few fields. Every field looks at model through ng-model

On main page user can dynamically add multiple exemplars of my component.
Is there any way to get data from all components models on page by one button pressed?

I tried to add callback function to this component that should return component model data. But it works only if I have one component on page. When user add few more nothing returns to parent controller.

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `parameter` in the `button` or use `ng-submit` in the `form` tag, then pass `param` parameter in your button function controller.

Like this

```
<form>
 <input type="text" ng-model="param.user">
 <button ng-click="click(param)">click</button>
</form>
```

or you can do it via ng-submit

```
<form ng-submit="click(param)">
   <input type="text" ng-model="param.user">
   <button>click</button>
</form>
```

in your controller: --

```
$scope.click = function(param) {
  console.log(param) // will return the input value
}
```

At least this is how I understand your question. Though you should provide the code you've tried so far so people can see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer from other forum
https://plnkr.co/edit/0PPwLq2SjKwVJWYpldgU?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  this.children = [];

  this.addChild = instance => {
    console.log(instance);
    this.children.push(instance);
  }

  this.getChildValue = function() {
    console.log(this.children);
  }

});


app.component('myComponent', {
  bindings: {
    addChild: '<'
  },
  controller: function MyComponentCtrl() {

    this.name = '';
    this.surname = '';

    this.addChild(this);

  },
  template: `
    <input type='text' ng-model='$ctrl.name' placeholder='Enter name' />
    <input type='text' ng-model='$ctrl.surname' placeholder='Enter surname' />
  `
});
```

Leave it here in case someone have the same problem
Sorry if my description wasn`t very clear